# commands through define

Tags: python, function, pygame

I was making a program in python with pygame so that when you press a button on the screen, it does a command. I am doing this through a define but I can't seem to be able to use the command. Here is my code (btw I'm using python 2.7.11)

```
from time import sleep
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (135,135,0)#(kinda green)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
pygame.display.set_caption('Testing')
running = True
def msg():
    print (20)

def button(posX,posY,length,width,color,color2,color3,command):
    a = (0,0)
    b = (posX,posY)
    c = (posX+length,posY+width)

    while 1:
      sleep (0.001)
      for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill(white)

        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
        a = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


        if (a >= b) & (a <= c):
            if (event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color3, [posX, posY,length,width])
                pygame.display.flip()
                command

            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color2, [posX, posY,length,width])
                pygame.display.flip()
        else:

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [posX, posY,length,width])
            pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.quit()

button(60,60,100,100,red,black,green,msg())
```

As you can see, I am calling another define from the variable command which I run when I click the button. When I run this and click the button, there are no errors just nothing happens. Can someone please tell me how to properly do this? I was searching all over google but I got nothing related.

Answer (score 0):

When you put `msg()` in the argument list to `button`, you're not passing the function as an argument, but calling it immediately and passing its return value (`None` in this case) as the argument. Get rid of the parentheses and you'll be passing a reference to the function:

```
button(60,60,100,100,red,black,green,msg)
```

Now you just need to fix up calling the command from inside the `button` function. Instead of just naming it, `command`, call it by adding the parentheses on the end:

```
        if (event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color3, [posX, posY,length,width])
            pygame.display.flip()
            command()
```

Comment: @AryanMisra, don't forget to mark answers as 'accepted'  (the tick) if you found them helpful.